# Java environment error

Tags: java, error-handling, runtime-error

I get the following error while trying to run a java program:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   at b.a.a.b.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
   at pcloud.systemtray.ASPAgent.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
   at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
   at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at b.a.f.a.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
   ... 9 more
```

I have no idia what's causing it or how to solve it.
I have java 7 u65 installed and the program works on other PCs.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Provide the code for this `b.a.a.b` class. Otherwise, we cannot see the problem. If it's an external library, then seems like you need to configure something else, but we won't know since you don't provide enough details to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's probably an external library because the program that I run while getting this error is Samsung Link - but it's a java error that I get in a windows dialog with java icon so I thought that someone gere can help me understand what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as shown immediately after accepting an offer of an upgrade by a working version of Samsung Link. The error persisted after uninstalling, cleaning and reinstalling this software.

After an extended conversation with Samsung (during which they blamed my PC for having a virus and me for being stupid because I couldn't find a non-existent download link), they eventually sent me a zip file and the following instructions:

> 1. Unzip the attached file to temporary folder.
> 2. Copy the extracted files (pCloudAgent-2.0.jar, pCloudCommon-2.0.jar, pCloudUtil-2.0.jar) to the installed path e.g.
>
>    C:\Program Files\Samsung\Samsung Link\lib\pCloudAgent-2.0.jar
>
>    C:\Program Files\Samsung\Samsung Link\lib\pCloudCommon-2.0.jar
>
>    C:\Program Files\Samsung\Samsung Link\lib\pCloudUtil-2.0.jar

For the benefit of others, the file can be downloaded from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10342307/allshareplay1408040042_SamsungLink_v2.0.0_patch.zip).

I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-updating jdownloader, may be a class file went missing because something went wrong with the original update.

```
Start menu > jdownloader > updater.jar
```